# Visualizing oscilloscope data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made a very crude oscilloscope (time on x axis, voltage on y axes)
data that is sent from my embedded device looks like this

```
while(1) {
    static volatile uint16_t dma_adc_sample[3] = {3730,1255,405};
    byteTXFunc(dma_adc_sample[0] & 0x00FF);
    byteTXFunc((dma_adc_sample[0] & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    byteTXFunc(dma_adc_sample[1] & 0x00FF);
    byteTXFunc((dma_adc_sample[1] & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    byteTXFunc(dma_adc_sample[2] & 0x00FF);
    byteTXFunc((dma_adc_sample[2] & 0xFF00) >> 8)
}
```

whenever the device boots it will also signal this with
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
byteTXFunc(0xAA);

to tell the vizualization program: I am ready now, you show osciloscope to user

Each element in array represents one channel (dma_adc_sample[0] = first channel, dma_adc_sample[1] = second channel, etc)
The embedded device (STM32H750) is sending this as fast as it can over UART (I cannot influence that)

Minimum value is 0, maximum value is 3730

Of course static data here is just for demonstration purposes, real data of course will change, it won't be static

So here is my python vizualization

```
import keyboard
import serial
import struct
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import threading
import queue
import os
import sys
import platform #Check OS

#User variables
SERIAL_PORT = 'COM7' #Windows = 'COMx' (COM33 for example), Linux = /dev/ttyACMX (/dev/ttyACM0 for example)
SERIAL_PORT_BAUDRATE = 115200

PYTHON_MAJOR_2 = False
PYTHON_VERSION_3_3 = (3, 3)
PYTHON_3_3 = False
PYTHON_VERSION_3_7 = (3, 7)
PYTHON_3_7 = False

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    PYTHON_MAJOR_2 = True

if sys.version_info >= PYTHON_VERSION_3_3:
    PYTHON_3_3 = True
if sys.version_info >= PYTHON_VERSION_3_7:
    PYTHON_3_7 = True

if platform.system() == "Windows":
    SERIAL_PORT = 'COM33'
elif platform.system() == "Linux":
    SERIAL_PORT = '/dev/ttyACM0'
else:
    print("You are running on an unknown operating system")

# create a queue to hold the incoming data
#data_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=1000)
if PYTHON_3_7:
    q = queue.SimpleQueue()
else:
    q = queue.Queue()

class DataCapture(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, q):
        if PYTHON_3_3:
            threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon=True)
        else:
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            threading.daemon = True
        self.queue = q
        self.ser = serial.Serial(SERIAL_PORT, SERIAL_PORT_BAUDRATE)
        self.channel = 0

    def run(self):
        data = []
        reset = 0
        running = False
        idx = 0
        
        #Compatible with both versions
        if PYTHON_MAJOR_2:
            bs = bytearray(b'\x00' * 6)
        else:
            bs = bytearray(6)
        
        while True:
            b = self.ser.read()
            if PYTHON_MAJOR_2:
                bs[idx] = ord(b[0])
                startByte = ord(b[0])
            else:
                bs[idx] = b[0]
                startByte = b[0]
                
            if startByte == 0xAA:
                print("RESET")
                reset += 1
                if reset == 8:
                    idx = 0
                    running = True
                    continue
            else:
                reset = 0

            idx += 1
            idx %= 6

            if running and idx == 0:
                us = struct.unpack('<HHH', bs)
                #print(us[self.channel])
                rounded_number = math.ceil(us[self.channel] / 100) * 100
                print("Channel: " + str(self.channel))
                print("Signal: " + str(rounded_number))
                #data.append(us[self.channel])
                data.append(rounded_number)
                self.queue.put(data)
                data = []
                
class KeyboardCapture(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, dc):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.dc = dc

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
                    sys.exit()
                elif keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl+c"):
                    sys.exit()
                elif keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
                    self.dc.channel = 0
                elif keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
                    self.dc.channel = 1
                elif keyboard.is_pressed('3'):
                    self.dc.channel = 2
            except:
                break

# function to update the plot with the latest data
def update_plot(frame, signal, ax):
    while not q.empty():
        data = q.get()
         # Scale the voltage data
        max_voltage = 3.3
        max_adc_value = 3299
        scaled_data = [v * max_voltage / max_adc_value for v in data]
        signal.append(scaled_data)
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(signal)
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Voltage (V)')
    ax.set_title('Oscilloscope')
    
def main():

    # Start reading data off serial device
    dc = DataCapture(q)
    dc.start()

    # create the figure and axes
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # initialize the signal array
    signal = []

    # create the animation object
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, fargs=(signal, ax), interval=1)

    # create and start the keyboard capture thread
    kc = KeyboardCapture(dc)
    kc.start()
    
    os.system('cls')
    print("To start reset your MCU")

    # show the plot
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It works, the only problem is that as time runs, data will not be visualized properly (more time has passed, fewer points will be visualized, and as enough time has passed you will not see the difference between the jump from 408 to 1000 any more, it will just average it out), which is not what I want (since it becomes impossible to see a sine wave or square wave, etc.)

I would like to add some kind of a time base (so I could zoom on a signal), but not sure how to do this properly if using matplotlib

This visualization is also very slow (not sure why, and how to make it faster, I cannot speed up UART sadly, but even with UART it should acquire the data faster, but if using Matplotlib there is some bottleneck somewhere, which is even slower then UARTs 115200 baud)

So I hope someone knows how to solve this (speed is not as important as having a time base)

Comment: Since you're plotting more and more data each time, it wouldn't surprise me if it gets slower and slower. What if you dropped old data from `signal` when `signal` gets too big?

Comment: I don't think this gets slower over time, its just generaly slow

And I did check q.qsize() and its 0 most of the time, so I guess my queue empties itself out